# How to alter table using cursor variable in execute immediate statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, alter

I have 7 tables in PS server, who have data from last 3 years(Billions of records). Requirement is to move all the data to a back up table except the last months data. So we approach:

- 1) to change the existing table name as back up table
- 2) and then create new table
- 3) and then move the 3 months data to new table.

This way data processing will be fast.

I tried with below query to change the table name but its not worked. Can any one help. It's high priority.

```
declare 
 sql_stmt varchar2(1000); 
 cursor c1 is select table_name from staging_clear; 
 type t1 is table of c1%rowtype; 
 curtype t1;
 begin 
 open c1; 
 fetch c1 bulk collect into curtype;  
 for i in 1..curtype.count loop  
 sql_stmt:= 'begin 
          alter table  '||curtype(i).table_name||' rename to '|| curtype(i).table_name||'_bkp';
          dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt);
   execute immediate sql_stmt; 
   dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt); 
  end loop;  
 end;
```

Error report:

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 11: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "ALTER" when expecting one of the following:begin case declare exit
>   for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with
>      << close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
>   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe ORA-06512: at line
>   13
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: Loose the begin in your sql_stmt

Comment: I have high priorities too ...

Answer (score 0):

the statement is broken: just write 'ALTER TABLE' and forget about the 'begin'

```
sql_stmt:= 'alter table  '||curtype(i).table_name||' rename to '|| curtype(i).table_name||'_bkp';
```